# Random product collection from custom module extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List not working

Tags: magento-1.8, collection, product-collection, random

This code is not working

```
class My_Module_Block_New_New extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List {
...
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);

        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('newproduct', 1)
                   ->setPage(1, $this->getProductsCount())->load()
                   ->addStoreFilter()
                   ->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));

        echo $collection->getSelect();

        $this->_productCollection = $collection;
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

echo $collection->getSelect();

```
SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`description`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`manufacturer`, `e`.`manufacturer_value`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`is_imported`, `e`.`gammes`, `e`.`gammes_value`, `e`.`ean`, `e`.`delivery_time`, `e`.`inchoo_featured_product`, `e`.`newproduct`, `e`.`coup_de_coeur`, `e`.`contenance`, `e`.`prix_salon`, `e`.`promo_du_mois`, `e`.`volume_weight`, `e`.`code_video`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '3' WHERE (e.newproduct = '1') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

Based on others topics getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()')) should work but not in my case, what am i doing wrong ?!

Thx

**EDIT**
This code is working

```
$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
$collection->addStoreFilter();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('newproduct', 1);
$collection->setPage(1, $this->getProductsCount())->load();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('newproduct', 1);
        Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
        $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
        $collection->addStoreFilter();

    $numProducts = $this->getProductsCount()?$this->getProductsCount():0
    $collection->setPage(1, $numProducts);

        $this->_productCollection = $collection;
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Comment: your solution is working. So in the end i had to put getSelect())>order('rand()'); at the first position and also syntaxe error (use $collection->...; at each row)

Comment: Don't use `ORDER BY RAND()` on a large catalog, [it has performance issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211329/quick-selection-of-a-random-row-from-a-large-table-in-mysql)

Comment: yes,i have agree with you...

Answer (score 1):

### Performant Solution Without `ORDER BY RAND()`

`ORDER BY RAND()` is unperformant because it results in a resource intensive temp table copy. It has to load all results into a temporary table, assign a random number to each row and then sort without any index. Instead we retrieve all candidate ids (this is faster and the amount of data is managable even for large catalogs), pick some randomly and retrieve these rows directly.

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $productCollection
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

    $numberOfItems = $this->getProductCount();
    $candidateIds = $productCollection->getAllIds();
    $choosenIds = [];
    $maxKey = count($candidateIds)-1;
    while (count($choosenIds) < $numberOfItems)) {
        $randomKey = mt_rand(0, $maxKey);
        $choosenIds[$randomKey] = $candidateIds[$randomKey];
    }    
    $productCollection->addIdFilter($choosenIds);

    $productCollection
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addUrlRewrite();

    return $productCollection;
}
```

See also: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78694/243

Or read about it in detail in my blog: http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2015/09/show-random-products-in-magento-you-are-doing-it-wrong/: